# i got'float' object is not iterable hence i used str to convert it to string but dosent work

Tags: python, pdf-generation

im trying  to generate a pdf file from this code i typed str but dosent work with me still got the same erorr.

```
reshaped_text3 = str(arabic_reshaper.reshape(flatmeate1.pays(bill, flatmate2))) 
bidi_text3 = str(get_display(reshaped_text3)) 
pdf.drawCentredString(290, 270, bidi_text3)
print("Mohamed Pays", mohamed.pays(bill=the_bill, flatmate2=marry))
print("Marry Pays", marry.pays(bill=the_bill, flatmate2=mohamed))
pdf_report = PdfReport(filename='tarek.pdf')
pdf_report.generate(flatmeate1=mohamed, flatmate2=marry, bill=the_bill)
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\20102\PycharmProjects\bill-project\main.py", line 85, in <module>
pdf_report.generate(flatmate1=mohamed, flatmate2=marry, bill=the_bill)

File "C:\Users\20102\PycharmProjects\bill-project\main.py", 
line 64, in generate reshaped_text3 = str(arabic_reshaper.reshape(flatmate1.pays(bill, flatmate2)))


  File "C:\Users\20102\PycharmProjects\bill-project\venv\lib\site-packages\arabic_reshaper\arabic_reshaper.py", 
line 125, in reshape for letter in text:

 TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace and the full error message.

Comment: i edited the traceback

Comment: (1) The traceback is not from the code you posted. Code has `flatmeate1` but the error was was caused by a line with `flatmate1`. Before you object *but that was just a typo*, consider that you might have made other, less unimportant, errors. (2) It is clear that `pdf_report.generate()` has a problem with the data you are passing it. But without knowing what is in the variables `mohamed` and `marry` and the file `tarek.pdf` it's impossible to be more specific. I suspect you may need to learn how to use your development environment's debugger.